# How "Azure ML export data to SQL database by insert in a row of database."

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-machine-learning-service

I can only export data from AzureML by write instead to database that created previously. I need to know How to insert and fetch the data continuously the database because I need to use old data as well as the new data that get as the AzureML output to plot graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a web service from the AzureML experiment.
2. Access the web service using a program you written from C# or any language.
3. You can get the output of the web service as a JSON.
4. Use typical SQL ADD/UPDATE queries to update the table
5. When giving an input for the web service, fetch the data from the DB and pass as the JSON for it.